# How do you set the RAILS_ENV variable when using RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I have a rake task in my rails app that has a different absolute filepath compared between prod and dev. I have a different database username/pass that differs between prod and dev. I can't seem to get the RAILS_ENV variable to be set within RVM in order to tell each server what their role is. Is there a way to do this?

My workaround has been to do the following for all rake tasks:

`RAILS_ENV=development rake routes`

`RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Been having similar problems (not with RVM though). One way we did it was to assign `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` through `envrionment.rb`

It's not the actual answer, but it will give you some ideas:

```
#config/environment.rb
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "staging"
```

You may wish to look at assigning environment vars in RVM here: http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-make-system-wide-rvm-installations-work-with-cron-monit-delayed_job-and-passenger-1021.html

Comment: Adding that to environment.rb didn't seem to do anything. I simply created an alias in .bashrc so that 'rake' = 'RAILS_ENV=development rake'